# Laravel - trouble with Eloquent Collection methods such as last()

Tags: laravel

I have a variable `$courses` that in my debugger is shown as type `App/Courses`

In the model, there is a one to many relation and I retrieve these related items in the model and then access as `$courses->relateditems`

In the debugger, `$courses->relateditems` is shown as type `Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection`

Ok, all makes sense.

I want to get last item in the `$courses->relateditems` collection. So I try

```
$courses->relateditems->last()->startdate
```

But this is not returning the value that I know exists. And when I evaluate the expression `$courses->relateditems->last()` in the debugger I get this in my laravel.log:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active in /app/Courses.php:68
```

I am just not sure what is going on. I know I can use DB queries to just get the data I need, but I have a model event triggering a function and that function receives the `$courses` object/model (or however we name it) and I am just trying to get this working as above.

Ideas on what I am doing wrong?

thanks,
Brian

Comment: Can this be an edge case where $courses->relateditems is empty?

Comment: I cleared my database and recreated the data and now it is working. So I think maybe earlier when I was debugging I didn't let a function finish and the data become messed up.

Comment: What is on line 68 of your Courses class?

Comment: Not sure, I have various model events and so I had data changing at various stages and I overlooked what can happen when not letting things run to completion! But that line 68 is not causing problems anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here based on the error you have at the bottom of your post is a mistake in your code.

However, I think you've misunderstood how Laravel relationships work. They essentially come in two forms on a model, that of a property and that of a method.

`relateditems` Is a magic property that will return the result of a simple select on the relationship if one has already been performed. If one hasn't been performed it will perform one and then return it, known as eager loading.

`relateditems()` Is a method that returns a query builder instance for that relationship.

By calling `relateditems->last()` you're loading ***ALL*** related items from the database and then getting the last, which is less than optimal.

The best thing for you to do is this:

```php
$course->relateditems()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
```

This will get the first item return, however, since we've ordered it by `id` in descending order, it'll be reversed from what could be considered its default ordering. Feel free to change the `id` to whatever you want.